# preprocess csv files to convert key values to lowercase when using Hybris hotfolder

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

CSV files are having data in uppercase for keys like UID, is there a way to convert UID to lowercase and save when using hot folder in hybris. A change on our data source will take more time than hybris change.

I am thinking of creating a LowerCaseValueTranslator for impex. is it a good approach?

I have explored LowerCaseValueTranslator path.

```
  @Override
    public Object importValue(final String valueExpr, final Item toItem) throws JaloInvalidParameterException
    {
        clearStatus();
        Double result = null;
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(valueExpr))
        {
            try
            {
                result = valueExpr.toLowerCase();
            }
            catch (final NumberFormatException exc)
            {
                setError();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I expect that it will work - is this the best approach to do this

Answer (score 0):

Is the data/UID autogenerated by Hybris, or is it a custom value from user?

In any case, a translator is a good approach to do what you want (assuming the data is a custom value). If it is autogenerated by Hybris, I would keep it as-is.

Comment: Yes..thats what I did..used translator for custom value.

Comment: @EulerRule Good to know what it work. By the way, feel free to Upvote and Accept this answer, so that we can consider it as Solved. Have a good day! :)